# KVM: centos get no bridged ip on fedora

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, fedora, bridge, systemd-networkd

I've installed on my fedora machine centos as vm over kvm. My vm does not get an ip-address from my dhcp server over the bridge interface. When I want to active the interface via `nmtui` on my centos machine I get the following error:

[image: nmtui-error]

On my hostsystem I use instead the NetworkManager systemd-networkd to create a bridge interface for my vm's. The example blow are excerpts of my systemd-networkd configuration.

**br0.netdev**

```sh
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

**eno0s31f6.network**

```sh
[Match]
Name=enp0s31f6

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

**br0.network**

```sh
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=10
# UseDNS=false
```

The XML specified my centos VM

```xml
<domain type='kvm' id='2'>
  <name>orbisos</name>
  <uuid>d7c4c0af-d3e3-426e-93ef-5435048acd6b</uuid>
  <metadata>
    <libosinfo:libosinfo xmlns:libosinfo="http://libosinfo.org/xmlns/libvirt/domain/1.0">
      <libosinfo:os id="http://centos.org/centos/7.0"/>
    </libosinfo:libosinfo>
  </metadata>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>2</vcpu>
  <resource>
    <partition>/machine</partition>
  </resource>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-3.1'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact' check='full'>
    <model fallback='forbid'>Skylake-Client-IBRS</model>
    <vendor>Intel</vendor>
    <feature policy='require' name='ss'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='vmx'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='hypervisor'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='tsc_adjust'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='clflushopt'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='umip'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='md-clear'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='ssbd'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='xsaves'/>
    <feature policy='require' name='pdpe1gb'/>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/var/lib/libvirt/images/orbisos.qcow2'/>
      <backingStore/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <alias name='virtio-disk0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <alias name='sata0-0-0'/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='qemu-xhci' ports='15'>
      <alias name='usb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <alias name='ide'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'>
      <alias name='pcie.0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x10'/>
      <alias name='pci.1'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='2' port='0x11'/>
      <alias name='pci.2'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='3' port='0x12'/>
      <alias name='pci.3'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x13'/>
      <alias name='pci.4'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0x14'/>
      <alias name='pci.5'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0x15'/>
      <alias name='pci.6'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='7' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='pcie-root-port'/>
      <target chassis='7' port='0x16'/>
      <alias name='pci.7'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'>
      <alias name='virtio-serial0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:4e:23:d5'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <serial type='pty'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='isa-serial' port='0'>
        <model name='isa-serial'/>
      </target>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </serial>
    <console type='pty' tty='/dev/pts/1'>
      <source path='/dev/pts/1'/>
      <target type='serial' port='0'/>
      <alias name='serial0'/>
    </console>
    <channel type='unix'>
      <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/domain-2-orbisos/org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/>
      <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0' state='disconnected'/>
      <alias name='channel0'/>
      <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </channel>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'>
      <alias name='input0'/>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input1'/>
    </input>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'>
      <alias name='input2'/>
    </input>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='5900' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1' keymap='de'>
      <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/>
    </graphics>
    <video>
      <model type='qxl' ram='65536' vram='65536' vgamem='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/>
      <alias name='video0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </video>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <alias name='balloon0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
    <rng model='virtio'>
      <backend model='random'>/dev/urandom</backend>
      <alias name='rng0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </rng>
  </devices>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+107:+107</label>
    <imagelabel>+107:+107</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
</domain>
```

**brctl show**

```sh
brctl show
bridge name   bridge id           STP enabled   interfaces
br0           8000.86b1081ea310   no            enp0s31f6
                                                vnet0
docker0       8000.0242ac813766   no        
virbr0        8000.52540013d285   yes           virbr0-nic
```

**network interface from my hostsystem**

- 172.25.30.0/20, network via cable connection
- 10.6.235.0/23, network via wireless connection

```sh
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:81:d7:5d:d1:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::d681:d7ff:fe5d:d16f/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 86:b1:08:1e:a3:10 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.25.35.11/20 brd 172.25.47.255 scope global dynamic br0
       valid_lft 19893sec preferred_lft 19893sec
    inet6 fe80::84b1:8ff:fe1e:a310/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 34:f3:9a:d2:70:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.6.235.32/23 brd 10.6.235.255 scope global dynamic wlp2s0
       valid_lft 28338sec preferred_lft 28338sec
    inet6 fe80::36f3:9aff:fed2:7071/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:8e:7e:e1:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.150.1/24 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:13:d2:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:13:d2:85 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**hardware informations**

Dell Laptop Latitude 5590

**kernel**

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux morlk376 5.2.13-200.fc30.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Sep 6 14:30:40 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**libvirt**

```sh
$ libvirtd --version 
libvirtd (libvirt) 5.1.0
```

I hope anyone has an idea, why I get not ip address over the bridge interface from the hostsystem.

Comment: What is your physical hardware? What is the network it is connected to?

Comment: I have a Dell Latitude 5590. My network is via cable connected. I added some additional informations

Comment: What is the DHCP server, then? Have you checked it?